# Error in resuming JBoss Server (Wildfly 12.0.0.Final)

Tags: docker, jboss, wildfly, ejb-3.0, message-driven-bean

I recently deployed my application into local JBoss server and everything works just fine. Then I try to migrate the application into [JBoss/wildfly-12 Server](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly/) (Docker version) and now having a problem.

Here's a look into the log file:

```
TRACE [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) Scan complete
TRACE [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Scanning directory D:\ for deployment content changes
TRACE [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Scan complete
INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Server will resume
ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0215: Failed to resume activity org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponent$1@58921a50. To resume normal operation it is recommended that you restart the server.
```

I tried to restart the server but this problem always come. Afterwards, I tried to google up the problem and found [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-7860). I am not sure this is the right solution. Does anyone have the same problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with Wildfly 11.0.0.Final. Strangely, it only happens when I deploy to my Linux environment. It works fine on my Windows dev machine. Have you solved this by now?

Comment: Hello Moritz,

I already solved it. In my case, there are some misconfigurations in my external Message Queue application (WebSphere MQ). 
This problem happens because the server cannot connect to the required messaging services. In JBoss that could be resulted from e.g. false configuration in activemq-ra or wmq-jmsra.rar (Websphere MQ).
Thank you. 

Best Regards,

Andrew